# Displaying the right UIView when dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:completion: is called

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

Let me explain. I have multiple `UIViewControllers`. On my `MainPageController`, I have 3 UIViews. Let's enumerate it this way: the first UIView is called `LoginView`, the second is called `HomeView` and the other one is called `RegView`. Now in `HomeView`, there are multiple buttons that will lead to other `UIViewControllers`. For example, one button will lead to `StoreController`. Now if I am inside `StoreController` and I want to go back to `MainPageController`, I simply call:

`[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]`

This will send me back to the `HomeView`.

That is good. However, inside the `StoreController`, there are buttons which will supposedly direct me to `LoginView` or `RegView`, whichever button was tapped. The problem is when the method `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]`, it only take me back to `HomeView`, no matter which button I pressed.

So how will I display the right UIView once the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` is called?

**EDIT:**

This is how I show the UIViews:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  //Initialize the views here...
}

-(void)showViewByTag:(NSInteger)tag
{
   if (tag == 1)
   {
     [self.view addSubview:loginView];
   }
   else if (tag == 2)
   {
     [self.view addSubview:homeView];
   }
   else
   {
     [self.view addSubview:regView];
   }
}
```

Now I call the method `showViewByTag:` somewhere in my code to display the views.

Comment: How are the 3 views handled by MainPageController? are they overlapped subviews of a common view? how do you manage those?

Comment: I created a function which will show the UIViews depending on the "viewTag". For example, if the viewTag == 1, it will show the LoginView. If the viewTag == 2, it will show the HomeView. I'll show it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could try and do is following: before calling `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]` (and thus go back to your home view), change the view currently displayed in your `MainPageController`:

```
[(MainPageController*)self.presentingViewController showViewByTag:desiredViewTag];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES...];
```

If you are worried at the cast and you foresee that `self.presentingViewController` might be not of MainPageController type on some occasions, then you can check explicitly for its type:

```
if ([self.presentingViewController isKindOf:[MainPageController class]])
    [(MainPageController*)self.presentingViewController showViewByTag:desiredViewTag];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES...];
```

For this to compile, MainPageController.h must be imported in your modal controller class.

Comment: It seems like `self.presentingViewController` does not call the methods for MainPageController (even if MainPageController is StoreController's presentingViewController).

Comment: what do you mean by: does not call? do you get a crash? or is self.presentingViewController nil?

Comment: self.presentingViewController is not equal to nil and I declared `showViewByTag` method as a forward declaration. Yet when I do this: `[self. presentingViewController showViewByTag:2]`, it says `'UIViewController' may not respond to 'showViewByTag'....`.

Comment: I understand that you did not try to run the program: if `self. presentingViewController` is actually of `MainPageController` type, there will be no problem. See my edit for a way to prevent the warning.

Comment: Hi! It finally worked! I'm confused of the warning because it actually worked, yet it keeps saying the same warning. Still though, thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad it helped! the warning comes from the definition of `self.presentingViewController`, which is a generic `UIViewController`, not your custom `MainPageController`. The way to remove it is via the cast I proposed in my answer. Or you could use notifications to make the dependency between the modal and the presenting controller even looser and bypass `self.presentingViewController` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

dismissModalViewController will always bring back the viewController which presented it ,and that can be only one,so the ideal way would be to tell the navigationController to initWith your desired viewController..

eg on regButton click in the presented modalview

```
RegViewController *regViewController = [[RegViewController alloc]initWithNibNam:@"RegViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController initWithRootViewController:regViewController];
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. Let me clarify. `RegView` (as well as `LoginView` and `HomeView`) are UIViews inside the `MainPageController`. What I want is to display the right view when the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` was called on other UIViewControllers.

Comment: after checking your updated code ,it seems dismissModalViewController is not the way to go,since the views are added to the MainPageController,try removing them from superview.

Comment: [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; shall take you to the MainPageController